# AES Encryption C#

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

EDIT: Added my hash code to the bottom of this.

I am having some problems creating a message integrity key for a solution I am creating. In order for this to be correct I need to use the following settings.

Mode: ECB
KeySize: 256
BlockSize: 128
Padding: PKCS7

I am using a 32 byte key which is generated from a file and also a blank IV as I understand ECB does not require one.

My problem I am expecting a 48 byte output from this before the encoding however I am receiving a 64 byte output.

I have shown some code below about how am I am trying to achieve this but I am not having much success.

```
public static string Encrypt(string hash) {

        // Create a new instance of the AesManaged
        // class.  This generates a new key and initialization 
        // vector (IV).
        using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged()) {

            myAes.Key = File.ReadAllBytes("keyfile");
            myAes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            myAes.IV = new byte[16] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            myAes.KeySize = 256;
            myAes.BlockSize = 128;
            myAes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            // Encrypt the string to an array of bytes.
            byte[] encrypted = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(hash, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            // Decrypt the bytes to a string.
            string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(encrypted, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);

            //Display the original data and the decrypted data.
            Console.WriteLine("Original:   {0}", hash);
            Console.WriteLine("Round Trip: {0}", roundtrip);

            // Encode
            string encoded = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

            Console.WriteLine("Encoded:    {0}", encoded);
            return encoded;
        }
    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV) {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        byte[] encrypted;
        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged()) {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt)) {

                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;
    }

static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }

        public static string getHashSha256(string text) {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        SHA256Managed hashstring = new SHA256Managed();
        byte[] hash = hashstring.ComputeHash(bytes);
        string hashString = string.Empty;
        foreach (byte x in hash) {
            hashString += String.Format("{0:x2}", x);
        }
        return hashString;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data that you're encrypting?

Comment: Sure, I am testing with this hash. 41a60829599a584da138ba4bab34dbdb3eb034b934bf9b6749ee1b66e570e6bf

Comment: Did you think that will prevent the NSA from reading your stuff? :-)

Comment: I assume not, it might help in delaying them though :)

Comment: Can you provide the DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes function please

Comment: I have added this to the bottom of the question.

Comment: Why are you even considering [ECB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29)?

Comment: This is a requirement for this solution. The backend of the solution (not written by me) uses this to check the message integrity. I guess if I don't follow what they use then there would be no way to validate this. I have read many bad things about ECB but unfortunately this is not my call.

Comment: Using AES in ECB mode for a MAC? That must be among the silliest things I've ever heard. Whoever wrote the backend should be spanked.

Comment: I know, I am going around in circles. The most puzzling thing is that they require the output to be 48 bytes. Is this even possible using a 32 byte key?

Comment: Key size has nothing to do with output size.

Comment: Ok, if that is the case my input is always fixed as it is the result of the SHA-256 hash. So I am assuming it is the AES settings that determine the output of the algorithm?

Comment: No. AES has a block size of 128 bits, so it takes 128 bits of input and produces 128 bits of output. This doesn't ever change. However, to be more useful, a block cipher like AES is usually used in a [mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) and the plaintext is [padded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)). (In your case these would be ECB and PKCS#7.)

Comment: @RLW Did you ever get this fully working using the code above (parts from MSDN)? I am coding against the same specification as you did and the byte array size return from EncryptStringToBytes_Aes() above is always 80 bytes and i am expecting 48 bytes. Some of the comments appear to have been deleted so cannot see the full conversation thread.

Comment: i think I figured this out. I changed all paramters to be byte[] instead of strings and I also changed this line "using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))" to "using (BinaryWriter swEncrypt = new BinaryWriter(csEncrypt))". It then increased the byte count of "encrypted" from 80 to 16 and then 48. fingers crossed :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PKCS #7 padding is defined such that padding is added in all cases. When the plaintext is a multiple of the block size, a whole block of padding is added. This is why the ciphertext is 64 bytes long when the plaintext is 48 bytes long.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was under the same impression. However the input for this AES comes from the result of a SHA-256 hash which always will be 64 bytes. Is it even possible for me to get from that hash to a 48 byte result following the AES?

Comment: SHA-256 produces a 32-byte hash. With 16 bytes of padding, the result is 48 bytes.

Comment: Ok, would the padding be added by the SHA-256 algorithm? Maybe I am padding it twice once with the SHA and again with the AES giving my a longer output than expected?

Comment: No. SHA-256 *always* produces 32 bytes of output. I think the problem is the fact that you hex encode the output of the hash.

Comment: Right ok, so I am producing a 32 byte input from the SHA-256. This in theory should result in 32+16(padding)= 48 from the AES? My code it currently producing a 80 bytes...

Comment: Yes. The problem is that hex encoding 32 bytes of data produces a string that is 64 characters in length.

Comment: Ok, so what form of encoding should I be using to keep the 32bytes to 32 characters?

Comment: Why do you have to encode it at all? AES accepts any bytes as input.

Comment: I realised that on amended it. I am now getting 48 bytes which is great. Thank you for your help. For some reason the result is different every time although I am using the same key, mode and input. I guess this would be part of a different question though. Thanks for your help

Comment: in answer to your question about getting different values every time it is run it is to with the order of the AES settings. Reordering them so .KEY and .IV are last ensures the result returns the same everytime